# raspberry pi red solid gren blink once

Tags: boot, boot-issues, led, bootloader

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB everytime when I power green light blinks once and the red solid light is on. I connected to the HDMI screen and there is no output on the screen. I tried restoring the bootloader using Pi Imager `` try different OS but the status of the LED has not changed
[image]

Comment: If you just power Pi connected to hdmi screen with no sd card, do you see the diagnostics screen?

Comment: No, the screen is blank, I added the picture in question. As you see the HDMI is connected the screen is blank, and the red solid light is on. when I turn on the pi the green light blinks only once

Comment: Are you powering a Pi4 from a laptop usb port? If so bad idea, get an official 5.1V 3.0A power supply.

Comment: I also tested on 5V and 3A adopter still the behavior is same blank screen, This is an old image,

Comment: Check the boot sticky but i suspect its dead. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: Hi. Consider generalizing your question show that your questions and answers on this paeg can reach more people.

Comment: Normally I would say the most likely cause is a faulty cable but that looks like a second hand Pi. They definitely shouldn't come in bubble wrap.

Comment: DO NOT put details in Comments - EDIT your question

Answer (score 0):

According to the Raspberry Pi 4 documentation the LED flash code for Partition not FAT or SPI EEPROM error. Consider checking for whether your SD card contains any non-fat partitions which are unrelated to the operating system you have installed as that may cause the warning flash code to appear.

You can also check another diagnostic guide [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151) for when your Pi is not booting.

Resources:

- [LED warning flash codes (Official Raspberry Pi documentation)[3](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes)
- [Rasperry Pi ACT LED error patterns](https://support.pishop.ca/article/33-raspberry-pi-act-led-error-patterns)